# PySpark concat two columns in order

Tags: concatenation, pyspark

I would like to concat two columns, but in a way that they are ordered.
For example I have dataframe like this:

```
|-------------------|-----------------|
|      column_1     |     column_2    |
|-------------------|-----------------|
|          aaa      |        bbb      |
|-------------------|-----------------|
|          bbb      |        aaa      |
|-------------------|-----------------|
```

Returns a dataframe like this:

```
|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|      column_1     |     column_2    |  concated_cols  |
|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         aaa       |       bbb       |    aaabbb       |
|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|         bbb       |       aaa       |    aaabbb       |
|-------------------|-----------------|-----------------|
```

Comment: what is the expected output if column 1 is axc and column 2 is ybz ?

Comment: It can be then `axcybz` - basically, I don't want to do usual concat, if there are two rows with the same column values - I want them to have the same concated value @SreeramTP

Comment: what is your spark version ?

Comment: 2.4.7_2.12 @Steven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version Spark >= 2.4

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "concated_cols",
    F.array_join(F.array_sort(F.array(F.col("column_1"), F.col("column_2"))), ""),
).show()
```

---

Spark <= 2.3 version.
With a simple UDF :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.udf
def concat(*cols):
    return "".join(sorted(cols))


df.withColumn("concated_cols", concat(F.col("column_1"), F.col("column_2"))).show()
+--------+--------+-------------+
|column_1|column_2|concated_cols|
+--------+--------+-------------+
|     aaa|     bbb|       aaabbb|
|     bbb|     aaa|       aaabbb|
+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Does it work in case of the null values?

Comment: @NorahJones I think the one in full spark 2.4 will work with null values. The one with the UDF no, but you can tune it a little bit. Replace `sorted(cols)` with `sorted([x for x in cols if x is not None])`